# How can normalize and plot this data?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I am trying to plot the following data in a Stacked Bar, but I don't know how to do it in the best way.

I have the following data:

```
**player**     **action**         **count**
player1        lost               15
               win                3
player2        lost               78
               win                61
               leave              6
                                  ..
player100      lost               43
               win                22
               leave              9
player101      lost               5
               leave              4
```

This is a Pandas series, so in each 'player' attribute can be relationated with three different actions [lost, win, leave], some players only have one of this other two and other three.

I would like to normalize this data and plot whit a staked bar like this.

I get the data from

```
df_players = df.groupby('players')['action'].value_counts()
```

so really I cannot access to the count like a row

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the count by the sum by level:

```
(df['count'].div(df.['count'].sum(level='player'))
            .mul(100)
            .unstack('action')
            .plot.barh(stacked=True)
)
```

---

**Update** from your comment, you can do:

```
(df.groupby('players')['action']
   .value_counts(normalize=True)
   .unstack('action')
   .plot.barh(stacked=True)
)
```

Comment: I cannot get the count attribute from here df_players = df.groupby('players')['action'].value_counts()